# old French: How was "ie" pronounced before "ie" turned into "je"?

Tags: ancien-français

I learned a few days ago that "j" is a fairly new letter. I looked up some samples of antique French books (pre-1633) and found a lot of words like (Saint)"Iaques", "ie", "iamais", "iambon", "iamais", "Ieanne"(d'arc), "iour", "iouer", "iolis".

A Google literal search (word literal in quotes) shows a whole bunch of text that uses "i" where I expect "j" to be.  For example:

[image: ESSAIS DE MONTAIGNE SUIVIS DE SA CORRESPONDANCE]

or

[image: A sample from Clelie, histoire romaine. Par Mr de Scudery, gouuerneur de Nostre ..., Volume 8]

or

[image: 1621 Ieanne D'Arc]

I tried to find a text on the evolution of the French language to try to find out when this change occurred and whether it still sounded like /ʒ/ or if there was some kind of dialects using the traditional /j/ pronunciations (like y in "yes") at some point, but I could not find any mention of this change online.

Does anybody know how these words sounded back then, did they still use /ʒ/ or was it /j/? And was it always /ʒ/ or was there a time when French used /j/ or /h/ instead?

Comment: Très intéressant, notons aussi l'absence de distinction u/v, écrit U en milieu du mot : **auez** pour *avez*, **souuenir** pour *souvenir*. Et V en début de mot : **vn** (*un*), **vous**.

Comment: En latin, les lettres I et J étaient la même lettre.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The change in spelling from i to j was not connected to any immediate change in pronunciation. Words like *iamais, iambon, iour* were already pronounced with /ʒ/ at that point, according to the Wikipedia article "[Phonological history of French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_French#To_Late_Old_French,_c._1250%E2%80%931300)" (not really a reliable source, but it agrees with what I remember reading elsewhere about this point).

The Old French ancestors of such words most likely contained an affricate /dʒ/, like the *j* in English *jump,* rather than the fricative /ʒ/, although I think there is a bit of uncertainty about this.

I don't think that /j/ was used at any time during the period in which we call the language "French". Ultimately, some cases of "j" do go back to /j/ in Latin, such as in *jus* from Latin *ius* /juːs/, although others go back to *g* as in *jambe* from Latin *gamba* or *z* as in *jaloux* from Latin *zelosus*.

The sound that is now /ʒ/ was never pronounced like /h/ in French. The pronunciation of Spanish *j* as a voiceless fricative /x/, /χ/ or /h/ is a further development from a series of sound changes from /ʒ/ to /ʃ/ to /x/.